# Continuity of an abstract integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Suppose $(Y, \mathcal A, \mu)$ is a finite measure space and suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set. Suppose the fuction $F:U\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfies the following property:

> For all $x \in U$ the function $y \rightarrow f(x, y)$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and bounded.

So we can define $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $$F(x)=\int_Yf(x, y)d\mu(y)$$

Suppose that for every $y \in Y$ the function $x \rightarrow f(x, y)$ defined in the open set $U$ is continuous and that there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x, y)|\leq M$ for all $(x, y) \in U\times Y$.

Then $F$ is continuous.

---

Well, my nose tells me to start a sketch by fixing $x_0$ and writing $|F(x)-F(x_0)|\leq\int_Y|f(x_0, y)-f(x, y)|d\mu(y)$. Then I would like to work in a small neighborhood $V$ around $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0, y)-f(x, y)|<\mu(Y)\epsilon/2$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon$ for all $y$ and for all $x \in V$. It would be easy to get such a neighborhood for a finite set of y's, but I don't know how to get if for all $y$ at once. Can someone help me?

Comment: Consider a sequence $x_n\to x$ and use dominated convergence.

Comment: Oh, now it looks so easy! Thank you